# How to connect my ATV app with my sender app?

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

i can not figure out how to connect my ATV app with my sender APP through a developer console. Should I have a custom web receiver anyway? Or can i have only Android TV app without a html5 app for chromecast?
Please help, i do not understand